# How can I add a foreign key constraint on an existing table column via SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm using Flask, Alembic, and PostgreSQL with SQLAlchemy. I have an existing table `location_messages` with a column `campaign_id`. This was created initially in the model with the code

```
campaign_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

I want to add a foreign key to it, so I updated the model with

```
campaign_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('campaigns.id'))
```

I ran the `revision --autogenerate` but it didn't create anything-- so I've been looking through the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKeyConstraint) but I can't grok the syntax for my usage. For what it's worth, creating the table from scratch (after dropping it) in Alembic is

```
op.create_table('location_messages',
[...]
sa.Column('campaign_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['campaign_id'], ['campaigns.id'], ),
sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
)
```

but for my life, I can't find a way to do this for an existing table. Is there a way to just get an instance of a table and assign a `ForeignKeyConstraint` to a column?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Alembic op you are looking for is [`create_foreign_key`](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.create_foreign_key).

```
op.create_foreign_key(
    'fk_location_message_campaign',
    'location_messages', 'campaigns',
    ['campaign_id'], ['id'],
)
```

It is recommended that you use [automatic constraint naming](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#constraint-naming-conventions) so that you can pass `None` as the name rather than naming it manually.

Answer (score 0):

ForeignKey just need to be Tuple ... so instead of `['campaign_id']` write `('campaign_id',)`

```
op.create_table('location_messages',
[...]
sa.Column('campaign_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(('campaign_id',), ['campaigns.id'], ),
sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
)
```

Comment: I downvoted because this has nothing to do with the question. OP is asking how to add a foreign key to an _existing_ table. Your code shows how to create a new table with a foreign key.

Comment: Upvoted, was looking for the creating table with the foreign key